# How to count only consecutive spaces in last collumn and print sum to first column

Tags: bash, text-processing

I need to be able to take the number of spaces in the last column and put that into a new first column. 
Unfortunately, its the number of CONSECUTIVE spaces I need to count, those in between the names need to be excluded from the count.
This is what I have done so far;

```
Line=$(head -n 1 Krep.07)
(head -n 1 Krep.07) | tr -cd ' \t' | wc -c > whitespace
sed -i '1d' Krep.07
White_count=$(head -n 1 whitespace)

if (( "$White_count" > 6 )) ; then
echo -e "$White_count\t$Line" >> Krep.07.2
fi
```

Krep.07 is an example input as above

Here is the output of head Krep.07.2

```
16      17.24137931     8.83    65      0       O       204457            Sphingomonadales
18      17.24137931     8.83    65      4       F       41297               Sphingomonadaceae
20      14.05835544     7.2     53      0       G       13687                 Sphingomonas
24      11.14058355     5.71    42      42      S       2219696                 Sphingomonas sp. FARSPH
23      0.795755968     0.41    3       0       S       152682                  Sphingomonas melonis
26      0.795755968     0.41    3       3       -       621456                    Sphingomonas melonis TY
```

As you can see it counts the spaces in between the words in the final column.
Desired output;

```
16      17.24137931     8.83    65      0       O       204457            Sphingomonadales
18      17.24137931     8.83    65      4       F       41297               Sphingomonadaceae
20      14.05835544     7.2     53      0       G       13687                 Sphingomonas
24      11.14058355     5.71    42      42      S       2219696                 Sphingomonas sp. FARSPH
22      0.795755968     0.41    3       0       S       152682                  Sphingomonas melonis
24      0.795755968     0.41    3       3       -       621456                    Sphingomonas melonis TY
```

I cannot work out how to only count consecutive spaces and not those in between words.

Comment: Isn't your desired output exactly the same as your input? What is the actual desired output? If I understand your script correctly, you want to insert a new line consisting of as many space characters as there were consecutive spaces in the original first line of your file. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming what you want to do is count the number of spaces making up the last field separator (the whitespace between the second-to-last and last columns).

Using GNU awk, you can split lines based on content using a suitable regular expression (`FPAT`), and retrieve the separators afterwards:

```
$ gawk  '{n = patsplit($0,a,"[^ ]+( [^ ]+)*",seps); print length(seps[n-1])}' file
12
15
17
17
18
20
```

*NOTE: these are the lengths as copy-pasted from your example - the fact that they don't agree with your desired output may be down to the site's formating tools*

Here, `[^ ]+( [^ ]+)*` means one or more non-space characters, optionally followed by any number of **single** space separated sequences of non-space characters. This regex ensures that the last (multi-word) column is treated as one.

You can then re-substitute these values and reconstruct the record:

```
$ gawk  '{
    n = patsplit($0,a,"[^ ]+( [^ ]+)*",seps); 
    a[1] = length(seps[n-1]); 
    out = ""; for(i=1;i<=n;i++) out = sprintf("%s%s%s", out, a[i],seps[i]); 
    print out
  }' file
12      17.24137931     8.83    65      0       O       204457            Sphingomonadales
15      17.24137931     8.83    65      4       F       41297               Sphingomonadaceae
17      14.05835544     7.2     53      0       G       13687                 Sphingomonas
17      11.14058355     5.71    42      42      S       2219696                 Sphingomonas sp. FARSPH
18      0.795755968     0.41    3       0       S       152682                  Sphingomonas melonis
20      0.795755968     0.41    3       3       -       621456                    Sphingomonas melonis TY
```

---

You may find it simpler to replace `patsplit` by `split` and specify a regex for the delimiters rather than for the fields ex.

```
split($0,a,"[ ][ ]+",seps)
```

The result should be the same.

Comment: that's correct, the site's formatting is affecting the output, however, the answer works perfectly when put into the command line.

Answer (score 1):

From a regex standpoint, I think you'd be looking for this:
`\s{2,}` -- which means "A space that is two or more".

It won't count spaces in between words.

It goes from this:
[image]

To this:
[image]